# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'media/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'

Tags: python, django

I have a file in the `media/` directory:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

When I in a test.py file to get it by `GeoIP()`:

```
from pygeoip import GeoIP

def getLatLon(ip):


    gi = GeoIP('media/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')

    data = gi.record_by_addr(ip)

    return data

getLatLon("113.210.32.76")
```

There comes issue:

```
File "/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/TestIOS/TestPython/testDemo02/ipaddr/tests.py", line 16, in <module>
    getLatLon("103.200.32.76")
  File "/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/TestIOS/TestPython/testDemo02/ipaddr/tests.py", line 10, in getLatLon
    gi = GeoIP('media/GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygeoip/__init__.py", line 118, in __init__
    self._fp = codecs.open(filename, 'rb', ENCODING)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 895, in open
    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'media/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'
```

It says the `FileNotFoundError`. why there comes this error?

Comment: You should use the full path. `os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'GeoLite2-City.mmdb')`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you, this works.